# How to get first login and last logout time from sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My table Data like this..

```
ID         Name       Date                     Time       Type

 1         aaa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    9:35:43     In
 1         aaa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    11:10:43    OUT
 1         aaa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    11:35:43    In
 1         aaa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    1:00:43     OUT
 1         aaa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    1:35:43     In
 1         aaa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    4:00:43     OUT
 1         aaa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    4:10:43     In        
 1         aaa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    6:35:43     OUT

 2         Baa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    9:35:43     In
 2         Baa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    11:10:43    OUT
 2         Baa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    11:35:43    In
 2         Baa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    1:00:43     OUT
 2         Baa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    1:35:43     In
 2         Baa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    4:00:43     OUT
 2         Baa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    4:10:43     In        
 2         Baa      2014-07-01 00:00:00:000    6:35:43     OUT
```

now i want to get only first in And last out detalis from the table using sql. how can i get please help me

Comment: what have you tried so far? i recommend you to have a look at MIN() and MAX() functions.

Comment: Why do you store time separate from the date?

Comment: Do you want to have this information for every day (LOGIN:30.07.2014 00:00, LOGOUT:30.07.2014 19:00, LOGIN:29.07.2014 01:00, LOGOUT:29.07.2014 14:00, ...) or you want to have only first login and latest logout (based on the example above:LOGIN:30.07.2014 00:00, LOGOUT:29.07.2014 14:00, ...)?

Comment: I want every day First login time and Last logout time..

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH LoginCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,
           Date,
           MIN(Time) AS MinLogin
    FROM   Table
    WHERE  Type = 'In'
    GROUP BY ID,
             Date
),LogoutCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,
           Date,
           MAX(Time) AS MaxLogout
    FROM   Table
    WHERE  Type = 'Out'
    GROUP BY ID,
             Date
)
SELECT T.ID,
       T.Name,
       T.Date,
       MinLogin,
       MaxLogout
FROM   Table T
       JOIN LoginCTE I
           ON T.ID = I.ID
              T.Date = I.Date 
       JOIN LogoutCTE O
           ON T.ID = O.ID
              T.Date = O.Date
```

Comment: You forgot group_by in your CTEs

Comment: you will have min dates of LOGINs and max times LOGOUTs for each day, may be author expects exactly this solution

Comment: I assumed that it would be logical to request min and max for each person for each day.

Comment: It might make sense, I asked author for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * 
  from <YOUR_TABLE_HERE> ttt
  join (
      select max(time) logout_time, name, date
        from <YOUR_TABLE_HERE>
       where type = 'Out'
       group by name, date) max_date_table on ttt.name = max_date_table.name and ttt.date = max_date_table.date and max_date_table.logout_time = ttt.time
  join (
      select min(time) login_time, name, date
        from <YOUR_TABLE_HERE>
       where type = 'In'
       group by name, date) min_date_table on ttt.name = min_date_table.name and ttt.date = min_date_table.date and ttt.time = min_date_table.login_time
order by name
```