# select first in and last out time from door access table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Here is my door access table, [dbo].[tblAccess]

```
+------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| EmployeeId | EmployeeName | Location |   AccessTime    | ReaderType |
+------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
| _1346      | A            | L1       | 7/11/2014 10:00 | IN         |
| _1347      | B            | L2       | 7/10/2014 10:58 | IN         |
| _1346      | A            | L3       | 7/11/2014 23:39 | OUT        |
| _1347      | B            | L4       | 7/10/2014 23:58 | OUT        |
| _1364      | C            | L5       | 7/11/2014 10:00 | IN         |
| _1367      | D            | L6       | 7/10/2014 10:58 | IN         |
| _1367      | D            | L7       | 7/10/2014 22:42 | OUT        |
| _1364      | C            | L8       | 7/11/2014 23:58 | OUT        |
| _1422      | E            | L9       | 7/11/2014 23:58 | IN         |
| _1422      | E            | L10      | 7/11/2014 23:10 | IN         |
| _1111      | F            | L20      | 7/10/2014 23:10 | OUT        |
+------------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+
```

---

conditions

- Assume Employees will be IN and OUT in same day.
- There will be multiple IN and OUT for same day for employees.So need first IN and Last Out.
- need to get details day wise,between two dates, group by EmployeeId
- (InTime, InLocation) or (OUTTime, OutLocation) can be null for an employee
- If (InTime) is null then FirstInLocation and duration will be null and same for OutTime(**shown in Result 1**). [If it is hard, then just dont show the details for the day for which IN time or OUT time is null(**Shown in Result 2**)]
- Duration = (FirstInTime - LastOutTime)

---

**Result Needed**

I want to select EmployeeId, EmployeeName,Date, FirstInTime, FirstInLocation, LastOutTime, LastOutLocation, duration.

*Result 1*

```
+-------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| EmpID | EmpName |   Date    | InLoc | InTime | OutLoc | OutTime | Dur(Hr) |
+-------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| _1346 | A       | 7/11/2014 | L1    | 10:00  | L3     | 23:39   | 13:39   |
| _1347 | B       | 7/10/2014 | L2    | 10:58  | L4     | 23:58   | 13:02   |
| _1364 | C       | 7/11/2014 | L5    | 10:00  | L8     | 23:58   | 13:58   |
| _1367 | D       | 7/10/2014 | L6    | 10:58  | L7     | 22:42   | 11:44   |
| _1422 | E       | 7/10/2014 | L10   | 23:10  |        |         |         |
| _1111 | F       | 7/10/2014 |       |        | L20    | 23:10   |         |
+-------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
```

OR

Just skip the null IN or OUT row. some thing like this.

*Result 2*

```
+-------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| EmpID | EmpName |   Date    | InLoc | InTime | OutLoc | OutTime | Dur(Hr) |
+-------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
| _1346 | A       | 7/11/2014 | L1    | 10:00  | L3     | 23:39   | 13:39   |
| _1347 | B       | 7/10/2014 | L2    | 10:58  | L4     | 23:58   | 13:02   |
| _1364 | C       | 7/11/2014 | L5    | 10:00  | L8     | 23:58   | 13:58   |
| _1367 | D       | 7/10/2014 | L6    | 10:58  | L7     | 22:42   | 11:44   |
+-------+---------+-----------+-------+--------+--------+---------+---------+
```

So far I have done some query with the following links. But its incomplete solution and i am new to CTE, so i cant edit any of the query given in the links.

- [How to get first login and last logout time from sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032928/how-to-get-first-login-and-last-logout-time-from-sql-server)
- [SQL Query for time In/Out attendance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236820/sql-query-for-time-in-out-attendance)
- http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/sql-l/query-to-pair-user-biometric-attendance-record-in-first-in-last-out-format-5132155

---

I have this query.

```
    ;with cte as
(select *, rank() over(partition by EmployeeId order by [AccessTime]) rn
 from tblAccess)

select src.EmployeeId, src.EmployeeName, convert(date, src.[AccessTime]) as [AccessTime],
concat(datepart(hour,src.[AccessTime]),':',datepart(minute,src.[AccessTime])) as [TimeIn],
concat(datepart(hour,tgt.[AccessTime]),':',datepart(minute,tgt.[AccessTime])) as [TimeOut],
concat(datediff(minute,src.[AccessTime],tgt.[AccessTime])/60,':',datediff(minute,src.[AccessTime],tgt. [AccessTime])%60) as [Hours]
from cte src
inner join cte tgt on src.EmployeeId = tgt.EmployeeId and src.rn + 1 = tgt.rn and src.rn % 2 = 1
```

It return results some what ok but not satisfy all conditions. I dont know how to edit the CTE as I am new to it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Instead of posting an image you should post it as text, then we could copy-paste it to sql-fiddle to get the sample-data and  to test our query.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want for the sample data.

Comment: there are rows where people leave close to midnight / the next day. are there records where they might leave after midnight as this will affect the the possibility of using date calculations with DAY.

Comment: Assume everyone will IN and OUT on same day.

Comment: Assume everyone will IN and OUT on same day...so employee "F" born at office? :D

Comment: That was a condition I specified in the question. Sometime In time or out time can be null.In that case just leave it as null and duration also become null

Comment: Can you have more than one IN, or more than one OUT times for a specific employee on the same day?

Comment: Yes...In a day any employee can IN and OUT more than one. So I need First IN and last OUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE tblAccess(
    EmployeeID      VARCHAR(20),
    EmployeeName    VARCHAR(20),
    Location        VARCHAR(20),
    AccessTime      DATETIME,
    ReaderType      VARCHAR(3)
)
INSERT INTO tblAccess VALUES
('_1346', 'A', 'L1', '7/11/2014 10:00', 'IN'),
('_1347', 'B', 'L2', '7/10/2014 10:58', 'IN'),
('_1346', 'A', 'L3', '7/11/2014 23:39', 'OUT'),
('_1347', 'B', 'L4', '7/10/2014 23:58', 'OUT'),
('_1364', 'C', 'L5', '7/11/2014 10:00', 'IN'),
('_1367', 'D', 'L6', '7/10/2014 10:58', 'IN'),
('_1367', 'D', 'L7', '7/10/2014 22:42', 'OUT'),
('_1364', 'C', 'L8', '7/11/2014 23:58', 'OUT'),
('_1422', 'E', 'L9', '7/11/2014 23:58', 'IN'),
('_1422', 'E', 'L10', '7/11/2014 23:10', 'IN'),
('_1111', 'F', 'L20', '7/10/2014 23:10', 'OUT');
```

**SOLUTION**

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        EmployeeID,
        EmployeeName,
        AccessDate = CAST(AccessTime AS DATE),
        AccessTime = CAST(AccessTime AS TIME),
        Location,
        ReaderType,
        In_RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId, CAST(AccessTime AS DATE), ReaderType ORDER BY CAST(AccessTime AS TIME) ASC),
        Out_RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId, CAST(AccessTime AS DATE), ReaderType ORDER BY CAST(AccessTime AS TIME) DESC)
    FROM tblAccess
)
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName,
    [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), AccessDate, 101),
    InLoc = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ReaderType = 'IN' AND In_RN = 1 THEN Location END), ''),
    InTime= ISNULL(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(CASE WHEN ReaderType = 'IN' AND In_RN = 1 THEN AccessTime END)), 1, 5), ''),
    OutLoc = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ReaderType = 'OUT' AND OUT_RN = 1 THEN Location END), ''),
    OutTime = ISNULL(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX(CASE WHEN ReaderType = 'OUT' AND OUT_RN = 1 THEN AccessTime END)), 1, 5), ''),
    Duration =  ISNULL(RIGHT('00' +             
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                    MAX(CASE WHEN ReaderType = 'IN' AND In_RN = 1 THEN AccessTime END), 
                    MAX(CASE WHEN ReaderType = 'OUT' AND OUT_RN = 1 THEN AccessTime END)
                )/60), 2) + ':' +
                RIGHT('00' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                    MAX(CASE WHEN ReaderType = 'IN' AND In_RN = 1 THEN AccessTime END), 
                    MAX(CASE WHEN ReaderType = 'OUT' AND OUT_RN = 1 THEN AccessTime END)
                )%60), 2)
            ,'')
FROM CTE
GROUP BY EmployeeID, EmployeeName, AccessDate
ORDER BY EmployeeName, AccessDate
```

**RESULT**

```
EmployeeID           EmployeeName Date       InLoc    InTime OutLoc  OutTime Duration
-------------------- ------------ ---------- -------- ------ ------- ------- --------
_1346                A            07/11/2014 L1       10:00  L3      23:39   13:39
_1347                B            07/10/2014 L2       10:58  L4      23:58   13:00
_1364                C            07/11/2014 L5       10:00  L8      23:58   13:58
_1367                D            07/10/2014 L6       10:58  L7      22:42   11:44
_1422                E            07/11/2014 L10      23:10          
_1111                F            07/10/2014                 L20     23:10
```

Comment: @FelixPamittan but i tried to get with night shift employee detail also.  e.g ) eve 22:10 to mrng 7:10