# How to get all in and out time of an particular employee?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given Table:

```
    id       time_stamp                  Access Type    
    1001    2017-09-05 09:35:00         IN
    1002    2017-09-05 11:00:00         IN
    1001    2017-09-05 12:00:00         OUT
    1002    2017-09-05 12:25:00          OUT
    1001    2017-09-05 13:00:00          IN
    1002    2017-09-05 14:00:00         IN
    1001    2017-09-05 17:00:00          OUT
    1002   2017-09-05 18:00:00         OUT
```

I tried this query below:

```
    select  *,       datediff(minute, first_in, last_out) as durationfrom    (
        select  id
        ,       min(case when [Access Type] = 'IN' then time_stamp end) as first_in
        ,       max(case when [Access Type] = 'OUT' then time_stamp end) as last_out
        ,       cast(min(time_stamp) as date) as date
        from    Table1
        group by
                id
        ,       cast(time_stamp as date)
        ) as SubQueriesMustBeNamed
```

when i try this query it shows only first in last out.

Desired Result:

```
    id      check_in    check_out  totalhrs  check_in check_out totalhrs  date           
    1001     09:35       12:00      2:25       13:00    17:00     2:00    2013-09-05       
    1002     11:00       12:25      1:25       14:00    18:00     4:00    2013-09-05
```

The result will be above like this .  Anyone help me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Its Already Available on stackoverflow [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453110/select-first-in-and-last-out-time-from-door-access-table)

Comment: send me link please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453110/select-first-in-and-last-out-time-from-door-access-table

Comment: which DBMS are you using? The answer can be very different for different DBMSs.

Comment: for one id you can have just two INs and two OUTs?

Comment: sql server 2014

Comment: thanks vijayvicks but result not apt for my table it takes first punch as in and second punch as out ,but in my table i have eventid '0' as in and '1' as out

Comment: not like two it will be more one employee have three & another have 5 and so on

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f71ce/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([id] int, [time_stamp] datetime, [AccessType] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id], [time_stamp], [AccessType])
VALUES
    (1001, '2017-09-05 09:35:00', 'IN'),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 11:00:00', 'IN'),
    (1001, '2017-09-05 12:00:00', 'OUT'),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 12:25:00', 'OUT'),
    (1001, '2017-09-05 13:00:00', 'IN'),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 14:00:00', 'IN'),
    (1001, '2017-09-05 17:00:00', 'OUT'),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 18:00:00', 'OUT')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
       id, cast(time_stamp as date) [date]
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm')         check_in_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm')     check_out_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 1 then 
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0) end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_1
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then time_stamp end),'HH:mm')         check_in_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then next_timestamp end),'HH:mm')     check_out_2
     , format(max(case when in_rank = 2 then
           dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,time_stamp,next_timestamp),0) end),'HH:mm') total_hrs_2
from (
      select
            id, time_stamp, AccessType, next_timestamp, next_accesstype
          , dense_rank() over(partition by id, cast(time_stamp as date) order by time_stamp) in_rank
      from table1 t1
      outer apply (
          select top(1) t2.time_stamp, t2.AccessType
          from table1 t2
          where t1.id = t2.id and t1.AccessType <> t2.AccessType
          and cast(t1.time_stamp as date) = cast(t2.time_stamp as date)
          and t1.time_stamp < t2.time_stamp
          order by t2.time_stamp
          ) oa (next_timestamp, next_accesstype)
      where AccessType = 'IN'
     ) d
group by id, cast(time_stamp as date)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f71ce/3/0)**:

```
|   id |       date | check_in_1 | check_out_1 | total_hrs_1 | check_in_2 | check_out_2 | total_hrs_2 |
|------|------------|------------|-------------|-------------|------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1001 | 2017-09-05 |      09:35 |       12:00 |       02:25 |      13:00 |       17:00 |       04:00 |
| 1002 | 2017-09-05 |      11:00 |       12:25 |       01:25 |      14:00 |       18:00 |       04:00 |
```

Comment: thank you ... but when i change values schema like INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id], [time_stamp], [AccessType])
VALUES
    (1001, '2017-09-05 09:35:00', 'IN'),    (1001, '2017-09-05 09:36:00', 'IN'),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 11:00:00', 'IN'),
    (1001, '2017-09-05 12:00:00', 'OUT'),
    (1002, '2017-09-05 12:25:00', 'OUT'),

;  the output will be id date check_in_1 check_out_1 total_hrs_1 check_in_2 check_out_2 total_hrs_2
1001 2017-09-05 09:35 12:00 02:25 09:36 12:00 02:24